# How to store data at the time of SETTING the timeout and retrieve it when the time is up ?

Tags: html, timeout

**How to store data at the time of SETTING the timeout and retrieve it when the time is up ?**

**Steps to run the program:**
By default the text field contains `apple`.
Then I click on the `30 secs` button .
Change the text field to `ball` .
Then I click on the `35 secs` button .
Change the text filed to 'cat' . 
Then I click on the `45 secs` button .

```js
function myFunction1() {
      myVar = setTimeout(function() {
        alertFunc(document.getElementById('age').value);
      }, 30000);
    }

    function myFunction2() {
      myVar = setTimeout(function() {
        alertFunc(document.getElementById('age').value);
      }, 35000);
    }

    function myFunction3() {
      myVar = setTimeout(function() {
        alertFunc(document.getElementById('age').value);
      }, 40000);
    }



    function alertFunc(a) {
      alert(a);
    }
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="age" value="apple">
    <input type="button" id="button2" value="30 secs" onClick=myFunction1()>
    <input type="button" id="button3" value="35 secs" onClick=myFunction2()>
    <input type="button" id="button4" value="40 secs" onClick=myFunction3()>
```

> **The result :**
>   After roughly 35 secs the first alert will display **cat** .
>   Roughly 5 seconds later the second alert will also display **cat**.
>   And,oughly another 5 seconds later the third alert will also display **cat** !!!

I think what is happening is the parameter is being recorded after the timeout is complete.

How do i overcome this ?

One idea I have, is when setting the timer I will push the parameter value onto a stack/array and then pop it when the timer is complete. But how do I identify the timer when it completes.

Not sure how to implement `promise-then` method here.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your timeout function display the value when they are being added, you should change the myFunctionX to this

`function myFunction2() {
      var v = document.getElementById('age').value;
      myVar = setTimeout(function() {
        alertFunc(v);
      }, 35000);
    }`
 
The problem of your code is when the timeout is reached, the callback function read the value from dom, that is the final value of doing your steps.

Comment: Cool !!! It works. Can you share me any good reference link where I can study in depth about this.

Comment: @DannyBoi This is really a basic of js. I‘m sure you will find this is easy after some practice。